# ViewPager finish on last fragment scroll

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have created default activity provided by eclipse with 3 Tabs and ViewPager. My question is, how can I make ViewPager, if I scroll on the 3rd Tab to the right (that would mean on the 4th Tab), to close the activity ?

Comment: you can see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

What if you added a transparent / Thank You / Credits / whatever 4th tab and then did something like:

```
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

which would then allow you to do something like:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if(position >= mPagerAdapter.getCount()-1)
            finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 ViewPager Tab;
       Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
          Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {                       
                       if(position==4)
                       {
                         finish();
                       }
                  }
                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
```